# Magic Square Code (java)

Tags: java, arrays, magic-square

I've been having an issue with my Magic Square code. It continually prints "This is a magic square" even when I'm positive it isn't.
You enter 16 integers, and then the code is supposed to run and determine whether the entered integers create a magic square (i.e. the sum of all rows, columns, and diagonals are all equal).

I can't figure out how to make it print false.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MagicSquare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        int [] [] square = new int [4][4];
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
            {
                System.out.println("Input value for row " + (row+1) + " column " + (col+1));
                square[row][col] = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
        }

        int [] sumRow = new int [4];
        int [] sumCol = new int [4];

        int sum = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row ++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col ++)
            {
                sum = sum + square[row][col];
                sumRow[row] = sum;
            }
            System.out.println("sum row " + row + "\n" + sumRow[row]);
            sum = 0;
        }

        sum = 0;

        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col ++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < 4; row ++)
            {
                sum = sum + square[row][col];
                sumCol[col] = sum;
            }
            System.out.println("sum columns " + col + "\n" + sumCol[col]);
            sum = 0;
        }

        int [] sumDiag = new int [4];
        sum = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 3; col > -1; col--)
            {
                sum = sum + square [row][col];
                sumDiag[row] = sum;
            }
            System.out.println("sum diagonal " + row + "\n" + sumDiag[row]);
            sum = 0;
        }

        int [] sumDiag2 = new int [4];
        sum = 0; 

        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col ++)
        {
            for (int row = 3; row > -1; row --)
            {
                sum = sum + square[row][col];
                sumDiag2[col] = sum;
            }
            System.out.println("sum diagonal 2 " + col + "\n" + sumDiag2[col]);
        }

        boolean bool = false;

        int k = 0; int j = 1; 
        do
        {
            if (sumRow[k] == sumRow[j])
            {
                k = j;
                j += 1;
                bool = true;
            }
            else
            {
                bool = false;
                System.out.println("Not a magic square");
                break;
            }
        } while ((k < 4) && (j >- 1));

        k = 0; j = 1;
        do
        {
            if (sumCol[k] == sumRow[j])
            {
                k = j;
                j += 1;
                bool = true;
            }
            else 
            {
                bool = false;
                System.out.println("Not a magic square");
                break;
            }
        } while ((k < 4) && (j >= -1));



        String TorF = "";
        if (bool = true)
        {
            TorF = "is";
        }
        else if (bool = false)
        {
            TorF = "is not";
        }

        System.out.println("This " + TorF + " a magic square.");

    }

}
```

Comment: Careful on `for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)`  Is that supposed to be `i=0`?

Comment: Are you using the debugger to verify your magic square has the data in it that you intended?

Comment: I recommend not beginning a variable name with an uppercase letter 'TorF'

Comment: `if (bool = true)` - The equality comparison operator is `==`. You used the assignment operator.

Comment: as soon as you encounter a false, you know it's not magic.

Comment: @eldarerathis states, the equality operator is `==`, but don't even use that. You want to test the boolean variable all alone: `if (bool) {`

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of issues in your code, as said in the comments.

First, you only need to verify the [main and secondary diagonals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square).

Second, your code to compare the sums doesn't work for all cases and doesn't compare the diagonals.

Also, the `if` in the end is just wrong. Do this instead:

```
if (bool) {
} else {
}
```

And here is a solution:

```
int order = square.length;

int[] sumRow = new int[order];
int[] sumCol = new int[order];
int[] sumDiag = new int[2];

Arrays.fill(sumRow, 0);
Arrays.fill(sumCol, 0);
Arrays.fill(sumDiag, 0);

for (int row = 0; row < order; row++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < order; col ++) {
    sumRow[row] += square[row][col];
  }
  System.out.println("sum row " + row + "\n" + sumRow[row]);
}

for (int col = 0; col < order; col++) {
  for (int row = 0; row < order; row ++) {
    sumCol[col] += square[row][col];
  }
  System.out.println("sum columns " + col + "\n" + sumCol[col]);
}

for (int row = 0; row < order; row++) {
  sumDiag[0] += square[row][row];
}
System.out.println("sum diagonal 0 " + "\n" + sumDiag[0]);

for(int row = 0; row < order; row++) {
  sumDiag[1] += square[row][order - 1 - row];
}
System.out.println("sum diagonal 1 " + "\n" + sumDiag[1]);

boolean bool = true;

int sum = sumRow[0];
for (int i = 1; i < order; i++) {
  bool = bool && (sum == sumRow[i]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < order; i++) {
  bool = bool && (sum == sumCol[i]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  bool = bool && (sum == sumDiag[i]);
}

String tOrF = "";
if (bool) {
  tOrF = "is";
} else {
  tOrF = "is not";
}
System.out.println("This " + tOrF + " a magic square.");
```

Furthermore, there are some things you could do to optimize this code.